# pass on value of id in another variable

Tags: joomla-4.x, variable

I want to pass value of id in new variable v_id so that if we are displaying news in frontend value of v_id can be shown in front end
Essentially the role which id do, can be performed by v_id
Pls guide

```
<?php
/**
 * @version    CVS: 1.0.0
 * @package    Com_Latestnews
 * @author     RM <rm@gmail.com>
 * @copyright  RM
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

namespace Latestnews\Component\Latestnews\Site\Model;
// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use \Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;
use \Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use \Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;
use \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ItemModel;
use \Joomla\CMS\Helper\TagsHelper;
use \Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject;
use \Joomla\CMS\User\UserFactoryInterface;
use \Latestnews\Component\Latestnews\Site\Helper\LatestnewsHelper;

/**
 * Latestnews model.
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 */
class DetailModel extends ItemModel
{
    public $_item;

    

    

    /**
     * Method to auto-populate the model state.
     *
     * Note. Calling getState in this method will result in recursion.
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function populateState()
    {
        $app  = Factory::getApplication('com_latestnews');
        $user = $app->getIdentity();

        // Check published state
        if ((!$user->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_latestnews')) && (!$user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_latestnews')))
        {
            $this->setState('filter.published', 1);
            $this->setState('filter.archived', 2);
        }

        // Load state from the request userState on edit or from the passed variable on default
        if (Factory::getApplication()->input->get('layout') == 'edit')
        {
            $id = Factory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_latestnews.edit.detail.id');
        }
        else
        {
            $id = Factory::getApplication()->input->get('id');
            Factory::getApplication()->setUserState('com_latestnews.edit.detail.id', $id);
        }

        $this->setState('detail.id', $id);

        // Load the parameters.
        $params       = $app->getParams();
        $params_array = $params->toArray();

        if (isset($params_array['item_id']))
        {
            $this->setState('detail.id', $params_array['item_id']);
        }

        $this->setState('params', $params);
    }

    /**
     * Method to get an object.
     *
     * @param   integer $id The id of the object to get.
     *
     * @return  mixed    Object on success, false on failure.
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function getItem($id = null)
    {
        if ($this->_item === null)
        {
            $this->_item = false;

            if (empty($id))
            {
                $id = $this->getState('detail.id');
            }

            // Get a level row instance.
            $table = $this->getTable();

            // Attempt to load the row.
            if ($table && $table->load($id))
            {
                

                // Check published state.
                if ($published = $this->getState('filter.published'))
                {
                    if (isset($table->state) && $table->state != $published)
                    {
                        throw new \Exception(Text::_('COM_LATESTNEWS_ITEM_NOT_LOADED'), 403);
                    }
                }

                // Convert the Table to a clean CMSObject.
                $properties  = $table->getProperties(1);
                $this->_item = ArrayHelper::toObject($properties, CMSObject::class);

                
            }

            if (empty($this->_item))
            {
                throw new \Exception(Text::_('COM_LATESTNEWS_ITEM_NOT_LOADED'), 404);
            }
        }

        

        return $this->_item;
    }
    


    /**
     * Get an instance of Table class
     *
     * @param   string $type   Name of the Table class to get an instance of.
     * @param   string $prefix Prefix for the table class name. Optional.
     * @param   array  $config Array of configuration values for the Table object. Optional.
     *
     * @return  Table|bool Table if success, false on failure.
     */
    public function getTable($type = 'Detail', $prefix = 'Administrator', $config = array())
    {
        return parent::getTable($type, $prefix, $config);
    }

    /**
     * Get the id of an item by alias
     *
     * @param   string $alias Item alias
     *
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public function getItemIdByAlias($alias)
    {
        $table      = $this->getTable();
        $properties = $table->getProperties();
        $result     = null;
        $aliasKey   = null;
        if (method_exists($this, 'getAliasFieldNameByView'))
        {
            $aliasKey   = $this->getAliasFieldNameByView('detail');
        }
        

        if (key_exists('alias', $properties))
        {
            $table->load(array('alias' => $alias));
            $result = $table->id;
        }
        elseif (isset($aliasKey) && key_exists($aliasKey, $properties))
        {
            $table->load(array($aliasKey => $alias));
            $result = $table->id;
        }
        
            return $result;
        
    }

    /**
     * Method to check in an item.
     *
     * @param   integer $id The id of the row to check out.
     *
     * @return  boolean True on success, false on failure.
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    public function checkin($id = null)
    {
        // Get the id.
        $id = (!empty($id)) ? $id : (int) $this->getState('detail.id');
                
        if ($id)
        {
            // Initialise the table
            $table = $this->getTable();

            // Attempt to check the row in.
            if (method_exists($table, 'checkin'))
            {
                if (!$table->checkin($id))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
        
    }

    /**
     * Method to check out an item for editing.
     *
     * @param   integer $id The id of the row to check out.
     *
     * @return  boolean True on success, false on failure.
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    public function checkout($id = null)
    {
        // Get the user id.
        $id = (!empty($id)) ? $id : (int) $this->getState('detail.id');

                
        if ($id)
        {
            // Initialise the table
            $table = $this->getTable();

            // Get the current user object.
            $user = Factory::getApplication()->getIdentity();

            // Attempt to check the row out.
            if (method_exists($table, 'checkout'))
            {
                if (!$table->checkout($user->get('id'), $id))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
                
    }

    /**
     * Publish the element
     *
     * @param   int $id    Item id
     * @param   int $state Publish state
     *
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public function publish($id, $state)
    {
        $table = $this->getTable();
                
        $table->load($id);
        $table->state = $state;

        return $table->store();
                
    }

    /**
     * Method to delete an item
     *
     * @param   int $id Element id
     *
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $table = $this->getTable();

        
            return $table->delete($id);
        
    }

    
}
```

Comment: (Not resolving advice, but a refinement) `$id = (!empty($id)) ? $id : (int) $this->getState('detail.id');` is functionally equivalent to `$id = $id ?: (int) $this->getState('detail.id');` because `$id` is unconditionally declared in the method signature with a default value of `null`. Personally, I'd probably write `$id ??= (int) $this->getState('detail.id');`  I do not know how to resolve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your question and code, you should change:

```
Factory::getApplication()->input->get('id');
```

To this:

```
Factory::getApplication()->input->get('v_id', 0, 'int');
```

Check Joomla\Input\Input is the one used to manage retrieving data from the application environment

Comment: thanks, indeed worked like charm.